How to browse files on a web server using a web browser like Firefox or Chrome?
Would someone be able to tell me how to browse all files in a particular directory on a web server using a web browser ? The web server is running apache linux. I'm using WinScp and have tried changing permissions to read for everyone including others, owner and group but it still does not display all files within a web browser. I get the following error:
Error 403 - Forbidden
You tried to access a document for which you don't have privileges.

What kind of files it does display and which not?

My apologies but I get a forbidden 403 server error. No files display.

You then don't have the permission to access the folder. You will need to include the config of the share in Apache and the permissions of the folder, for us to understand the problem.

Apache by default is going to prevent he is listing of the contents of a directory. WinScp has no support for what you want.  There is no secure way to do what you want through a browser.

Browsers don’t actually browse files. They just display responses sent by the server. The server must list the files. Because this is a potential security vulnerability, you must explicitly enable this. Like harrymc said, please provide the relevant Apache configuration bits like VirtualHost, Location or Directory.

I should have mentioned that my website is hosted on a hosting company's server. I pay money every month for web space. My apologies again. Could it be that the feature I want would not be available to the hosting company's customers ?

Maybe, maybe not. Why not ask their support?
